# how to refresh a from when a user control changes

Tags: c#

I have a UserControl that is just a list that a user can use to add drivers and edit their info. If some of the info is missing, on another user control there is a list that the background of one option can change to green(if the info is complete) or red(if some of the info is missing) but i cannot make the other userControl update neither the form where the userControls are located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Way. Set Timer interval
- You can set timer and refresh the list every second.

Second Way. Add Event which trigger changed
- [I could find here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/property-changed-events)

You can add event